# Please advise me software which restore sharepoint sites?

Tags: powershell, backup, site, restore

Here the restore means a restoring process from an backup had been created before a disaster.

Sometime I use SharePoint PowerShell:

```
Restore-SpSite http://mySp -path c:\my.bak
```

and Veeam software - Veeam Backup and Replivcation for backuping and Veeam SharePoint Explorer for restoring.

Are there any alternatives ?

Comment: I suggest you Avepoint : https://www.avepoint.com/products/sharepoint-infrastructure-management/sharepoint-backup/